# How call another thread run method from Jform

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, buttonclick, jform

When I performed button click event, it can't calling other and this class is implemented by Runnable interface. Here my problem is execution of these class taking more time while I calling through this button click event. But normal execution of runnable interface class is executing  very fast. Can any give me solution get out from these problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can start a new thread from your JFrame :

```
Thread th=new Thread(yourRunnableClass);
th.start();//This will run your `run` method in a seperate thread.
```

If your thread will do something related to GUI then you should run your thread as below. Because GUI of a Swing application should run in a single thread. The `Runnable` interface will run when the application is idle.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(yourRunnableClass);
```